# the scrollview is not scrolling at xib file

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I am new in iphone development.. I have added the scrollview in my app and added 10 buttons graphically inside the scrollview. but when I run the scrollview is not scrolling

my code is as follow

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1500,50)];

    [scrollview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
}
```

Comment: does the background color get set to black via your code up there?

Comment: And how did you link the outlet with you class?

Comment: how you are adding the button???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are taking scrollview in xib. So, you need to remove `[self.view addSubview:scrollview];` from your code and you can directly set properties of that scrollview in xib except setContentSize(that you need to set in .m file).

Or if you want to create scrollView manually, remove from xib and use this:

```
UIScrollView * content = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[content setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
//Here you can add those buttons to content view
[self.view addSubView:content];
```

Comment: also increase height of this scrollview. 50 is too small.